# Python Flask PUT and DELETE Methods when submitting HTML Form

Tags: python, html, flask

I have 2 forms on an HTML page with the same action URL (e. g. action = "/example"). In my Python Flask .py file, I have 2 routes with the same url, but I want 1 route to have the PUT method and the other to have the DELETE method (e. g. @app.route('/example'), methods=['PUT'] vs. @app.route('/example'), methods=['DELETE']). How can I do that? I have visited multiple websites and some examples I have seen include using jQuery or hidden inputs (e. g. ), but so far, these examples do not work.

Comment: Web browsers can not send methods PUT and DELETE. They only send GET and POST. You could fake them by sending POST and adding a form value, a hidden input as you've seen, with the real method.

Comment: I've tried setting the form method as "POST" and "<input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>" inside the form. But when I submit the form, the result keeps displaying "Method Not Allowed".

Comment: Are you adding POST to the method configuration in the route? You can pass a list so you can receive both: `@app.route('/example', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])`

Comment: When I did that, it works for the PUT route in my .py file. But when I do similarly for the DELETE route, it accesses my PUT route in my .py file. In other words, when I put "<input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="DELETE"/>" in the HTML file and submit the form with that input, it accesses "@app.route('/example', methods=['POST', 'PUT']" in my .py file instead of "@app.route('/example', methods=['POST', 'DELETE']".

Comment: That's because it is actually going into the route with the POST. You should check the value of _METHOD there and call the delete/put function from there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but what I did was: in @app.route('/example', methods=['POST']), I put "if request.form['_METHOD'] == 'PUT': {{do something}}" and "if request.form['_METHOD'] == 'DELETE': {{do something else}}". If this is what you mean, how would I redirect to another route that contains the PUT or DELETE method specifically, especially since both the PUT and DELETE routes in my case will have the same URL?