# form delete method in flask SQLAlchemy not working

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to let the page show person details with a button in the bottom to delete the person from the db and directs to home home page. The problem is that for some reason the delete method is not working..

```
@app.route('/venues/<int:venue_id>')
def show_venue(venue_id):
  data = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
  return render_template('pages/show_venue.html', venue=data)


@app.route('/venues/<int:venue_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_venue(venue_id):

    try:
        Venue.query.filter_by(id=venue_id).delete()
        db.session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error = True
        db.session.rollback()
    finally:
        db.session.close()
        if not error:
            flash('Venue was successfully deleted!')
            return render_template('pages/home.html')
        else:
            flash('An error occurred. Venue ' +
                  request.form['name'] + ' could not be deleted.')
        return None
```

inside the HTML:

```
...
    <form class="form" method="DELETE" action="/venues/{{venue.id}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Venue">
    </form>
...
```

The console shows no errors but it literally does nothing.. just returns to the same page..
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for the  `delete` function, you need to pass what you want to delete as parameter of the function.

```
item_to_be_deleted =  Venue.query.filter_by(id=venue_id)
db.session.delete(item_to_be_deleted)
```

EDITED:
Instead of using the html-form, if you send the query by Postman, for example, can you delete the entry?

According to the other post linked in the comments, Web browsers can not send methods PUT and DELETE. They only send GET and POST. So it might have something to do with that!!

If you change the method being passed by the browser, it might do the trick!

Comment: changed it to ven = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
        db.session.delete(ven)
        db.session.commit().. but still the same

Comment: I think the problem is not in the query because it doesn't show the error flash so i guess it couldn't reach the route

Comment: Instead of using the html-form, if you send the query by Postman, for example, can you delete the entry? According to the this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320031/python-flask-put-and-delete-methods-when-submitting-html-form, 
Web browsers can not send methods PUT and DELETE. They only send GET and POST. So it might have something to do with that!!

Comment: You're right! I changed the method to POST and it worked like charm.. thanks! (please put your reply in a separate answer so I can mark it as correct)