# Flask blog post is deleting the last blog post instead of desired one

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have made a blog post using FLask and SQLalchemy, whenever I want to delete a post, it is actually deleting the last post instead of the desired one.

Python code:-

```
@app.route('/post_farmer_delete/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST','DELETE'])
def post_farmer_delete(id):
    
    email = session["email"] 


    print(id)
    
    obj = db.session.query(Post_info).filter_by(PostID = id).first()

    if(Post_info.query.filter_by(Email=email).count() == 0):
    
        isPost = False
    
    else:

        isPost = True

    print(obj.Crop)

    try:
        db.session.delete(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('sellCrops.html',ispost = isPost)

    except:
        return "There was a problem deleting the post"
```

```html
 <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <form action="\post_farmer_delete\{{data.PostID}}" method="deletes"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="delete" id="submit" type="submit">Yes</button>

                                  </form>
                                </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320031/python-flask-put-and-delete-methods-when-submitting-html-form

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not working